# Making a component take a only a specific fraction of space (like 2/3 or 9/10)

Tags: java, swing, layout

Using layouts for me results in so much frustration that I end up using an absolute layout and then scaling the components manually.

Let's say I have a TextArea, and I want it to take 2/3rds of the screen.
What I would really like is having a GridLayout with 3 rows, and forcing the TextArea to take TWO of those rows at once.

So for example:

- Row 1 (Occupied by first textArea)
- Row 2 (Occupied by the same text area)
- Row 3 (Occupied by buttons)

Here's a picture using Gridbag layout (modified from the [java tutoria](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)l). I would like the area in green to be taken up by a single component.

[image: GridBagLayout]

This is just a way of expressing myself, I am positively sure that there are other ways (or layouts) for doing this. However note that I would also like to do this with other specific scales, such as 9/10.

That would save so much time. Thanks!

Comment: in that scenario, you usually don't want the buttons to grow when you resize the window, though, so you could as well put them to EAST of a border layout... But GridBagLayout or 3rd party layouts (like jGoodies Forms) can do what you want, I prefer Forms when the extra 100K jar size does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you should not be playing with absolute percentages, expecially on individual compoents. You should let a component display at its preferred size. So your example really doesn't make any sense. When you have a form with a text area and buttons. Then changes in size should affect the text area and not the buttons. Then you add a scrollpane to the text area so the scroll bar will appear or disappear as required.

However if for some reason you do need to use absolute percentages at a panel level you can use code like the following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    JPanel red;
    JPanel green;

    public GridBagSSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

        red = new JPanel();
        red.setBackground( Color.RED );
        red.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(300, 10) );
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;
        add(red, gbc);

        green = new JPanel();
        green.setBackground( Color.GREEN );
        green.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(300, 90) );
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.9;
        add(green, gbc);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.add( new JButton("Ok") );
        buttons.add( new JButton("Cancel") );
        buttons.setAlignmentX(JPanel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        add(buttons, gbc);

        addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(red.getSize() + " : " + green.getSize());
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new GridBagSSCCE() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The key in the above code is to start with a preferred size at your desired (10/90) ratio and to also set the weighty of the components in the same ratio.

If you want you can also check out the [Relative Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which was written specifically for this purpose.

Edit:

A GridBagLayout does not display the components in percentages. Just because you have two rows does not mean each row is 50%. The height of each row is dependent on the height of each component added in each row.

First you decide the preferred amount of data to be displayed in the text area. For two rows your would use something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(2, 40);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
```

Then you create a panel with buttons.

It may turn out that a text area with 2 rows is approximately the same size a panel with buttons because the panel adds a vertical gap above and below the component and the button has a relatively large border, but that is just a coincidence. But you should not force the text area to be more than half. Just let the layout manager and the pack() method do their jobs.

Now you need to decide what happens when the frame increases in size as this will determine the layout manager of the parent container. In this case I would probably use a BorderLayout so I would then use code like:

```
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.pack();
```

You don't care if the text area is half the frame or not. The pack method determines the relative sizes of each component based on their preferred sizes. If the frame increases the text area gets more space.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "You should let a component display at its preferred size." If you have a text area in a GridBag layout with 2 rows, the preferred size of a component added there is half the available space. In essence, the gridbag layout displays componetnts in percentages, I don't know why it's wrong with that. (Although I put two layouts inside each other in this case, border layout at the bottom so button's don't resize with the form). Please do tell me why though, I want to learn.

Comment: In this case, I didn't want the textbox to take only half the space, but a bit more than that. What options did I have apart from an absolute layout? That's why your code is good, thanks for helping.

Comment: @camickr awesome! thanks! that saves alot of work. Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CopyTextNorthPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel hidelLabel;
    private JLabel firstLabel;
    private JTextField firstText;

    public CopyTextNorthPanel() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
            hidelLabel = new JLabel("     ");
            hidelLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 0.5;
            gbc.weighty = 0.5;
            gbc.gridx = k;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(hidelLabel, gbc);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            firstLabel = new JLabel("Testing Label : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            firstLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            firstLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 8;
            gbc.gridy = k + 1;
            add(firstLabel, gbc);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            firstText = new JTextField("Testing TextField");
            firstText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            firstText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 9;
            gbc.gridwidth = k + 8;
            gbc.gridy = k + 1;
            add(firstText, gbc);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            firstLabel = new JLabel("Testing Label : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            firstLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            firstLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 20 + k;
            gbc.gridwidth = 8;
            gbc.gridy = k + 1;
            add(firstLabel, gbc);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            firstText = new JTextField("Testing TextField");
            firstText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            firstText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 29 + k;
            gbc.gridwidth = 21 - k;
            gbc.gridy = k + 1;
            add(firstText, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is (for me) a bit hard to understand, it's going to take quite a while to understand it :/
Thanks for helping though. +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that GridBagLayout would work in this particular situation as you don't have as much control over the relative widths as you'll need.  Instead I suggest that you check out [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), a layout that while not part of core Java is aa free download, is extremely flexible and powerful, and is available for Swing and several other GUI libraries.

Comment: It looks like MiGLayout can do exactly what I require, but I don't wish to add any 3rd party libraries to my application for the time being. I would like an example of how to do this with GridBagLayout and take up the space by one component like this: http://i54.tinypic.com/207b1b6.jpg (the area marked in green).

Comment: @David: by itself and as I've already mentioned, GridBagLayout won't do what you want. If you are adventurous you could try to sink your teeth into GroupLayout or create your own layout, but for my money, I'd use a third-party layout.

Comment: Ok. One last thing, is it possible to combine two or more layouts to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Learn GridBagLayout. Seriously, once you learn it you will be able quickly do all you need.
You might also find helpful some GUI designer. For swing I personally like the one in netbeans.

Layout are frustrating until you learn how to use them. Remember, that you are creating app for your users. They will be frustrated every time when they want to resize a window. You dont want that.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels nothing complicated if I put only JLabels in 1st. rows, 50 - 80 (with PrefferedSize) depends of Gradient and number of JComponents, then I have small required Gap on Top and matrix for whole Container :-) +1 both :-)